# Conditional Sort In Groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, group-by, sql-server-2014

Please consider this result set:

```
Name     Value1     Value2     Value3
---------------------------------------
ccc       1          2           3
aaa       3          4           3
bbb       2          8           5
Group 1   2          1           3
rrr       1          2           5
mmm       3          4           4
nnn       3          2           1
eee       2          6           5
Group 2   2          4           4
...
```

As you see the record in each group don't sorted in alphabetically order. How I can sort record in each group alphabetically?

The desired result set is:

```
Name     Value1     Value2     Value3
---------------------------------------
aaa       3          4           3
bbb       2          8           5
ccc       1          2           3
Group 1   2          1           3
eee       2          6           5
mmm       3          4           4
nnn       3          2           1
rrr       1          2           5
Group 2   2          4           4
...
```

**EDIT 1)**

Code for generat base result set:

```
DECLARE @tbl AS Table
(
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    Value1 DECIMAL(5,2),
    Value2 DECIMAL(5,2),
    Value3 DECIMAL(5,2)
)   

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('ccc',1,2,3)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('aaa',3,4,3)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('bbb',2,8,5)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Group 1',2,1,3)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('rrr',1,2,5)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('mmm',3,4,4)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('nnn',3,2,1)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Group 2',2,4,4)

select * from @tbl
```

Comment: Which groups? Show us your current ORDER BY.

Comment: Any query you prepared?

Comment: @GaurangDave My original query is so large and has many  logic. this is sample result that similar to my result

Comment: Without seeing your SQL this question can't be answered.

Comment: @jarlh as I said to GaurangDave this result didn't gain from simple query.

Comment: But how do you define the groups?

Comment: @jarlh I get this query from a `SP` and that `SP` wrote by another person and I can't change that `SP`. According to document each record belong to a group that beneath records that they belong to

Comment: There is no any information that value ccc belongs to group1.
Possible solution - add column, for example "group number" of int for each group. 1 for group1, 2 for group2/ and then sort result on :
order by group number, Name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from (
    select Name, value1, value2, value3,
        case when Name like 'group%' then SUM(Groups) over (order by (select null) rows between unbounded preceding and current row) - 1
        else SUM(Groups) over (order by (select null) rows between unbounded preceding and current row) end [groupingCol],
        groups
    from (
        select *,
        case when Name like 'group%' then 1 else 0 end [Groups] from @tbl
     ) a
) b order by groupingCol, Groups, name
```